# Возврат Объекта вместо массива примитивов

Tags: java, массивы, объекты, методы

Есть 3 класса, 1й- выполняет вычисления над двумя целыми числами(деление) и передает все результаты (в т.ч. промежуточные) вычислений во 2й класс для хранения, а 3й класс берет эти результаты и формирует вывод в консоль. Т.к. промежуточных результатов много, то приходится формировать и хранить их в таком виде(многомерный массив):

```
private int[][] makeArithmetic(int[][] result, int index, int dividend, int divisor) {
    int[][] calculatedResult = result;

    calculatedResult[0][index] = dividend / divisor;
    calculatedResult[2][index] = divisor * calculatedResult[0][index];
    calculatedResult[1][index] = dividend - divisor * calculatedResult[0][index];
    calculatedResult[3][index] = calculatedResult[1][index];
    calculatedResult[4] = new int[2];
    return calculatedResult;
}
```

Во 2м классе данные хранятся в таком виде:

```
int[][] commonValues = {
   {19, 6, 1, 4, 7, 5},
   {2459, 59, 19, 30, 20, 0},
   {76000, 2400, 40, 16, 28, 20},
   {2459, 59, 19, 3, 2, 0},
   {0, 0}
};
```

Как для практичности и читабельности можно переделать архитектуру, чтобы метод возвращал не многомерный массив, а, например, Объект, без использования коллекций? Соответственно и хранил?

P.S. количество значений в каждом массиве может менятся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен что разобрался с вашей предметной областью, но попробую:
1. Делаем интерфейс для формул:

```
public interface Calculatable {
  void calculate();
}
```

Делаем различные реализации. Пример реализации для Вашего метода:

```
public class CalculatableImpl implements Calculetable {
  private int index;
  private int dividend;
  private int divisor;

  private int calculatedResult0;
  private int calculatedResult1;
  private int calculatedResult2;
  private int calculatedResult3;
  public void calculate() {
    calculatedResult0 = dividend / divisor;
    calculatedResult2 = divisor * calculatedResult0;
    calculatedResult1 = dividend - divisor * calculatedResult0;
    calculatedResult3 = calculatedResult1;
  }
  public CalculatableImpl(int index, int dividend, int divisor) {
    ...
  }

  // тут же можно переопределить метод toString() и использовать его в "3-ем классе"
}
```

тогда Ваш метод makeArithmetic будет выглядеть так:

```
public Calculatable makeArithmetic(Calculatable calculatable) {
  calculatable.calculate();
  return calculatable;
}
```

Таким образом для добавления новой формулы достаточно будет добавить еще одну имплементацию Calculatable.

Comment: спасибо, попробую применить ваш вариант!